# Testing window.location.href in React unit tests using Mocha, Karma

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I have a simple react component where I have an onClick event which redirects to another page - the Google search engine (for testing purposes).

Here's the JSFiddle link for the React component - http://jsfiddle.net/t9dva2f7/

```
describe('Events', function () {
    it('should have click event state', function (done) {
        var events = Events();
        ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(events);
        ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(events.refs.button.getDOMNode());
        //Test to see if the page redirects to correct url?
        done();
    });
});
```

How can I test that the browser was redirected to the correct url? Should I be mocking window.location.href? Or is there something else ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use location.assign() to do the redirecting and in your tests, just mock the assign function.
Let us assume the following handleOnclick function in the component:

```
handleOnClick = () => {
  const redirectUrl = window.location.href.split('redirect=')[1] || null;
  if(redirectUrl) window.location.assign(redirectUrl);
```

Add the testUrl to your jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
  testURL: "http://localhost",
}
```

In your tests, mock the assign function and assert that it was called with the respective url.

Edit the location.href:

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'Test Title', '/testurl.html?redirect=http://localhost/redirecturl.html');

window.location.assign = jest.fn();

#invoke the handleOnClick function and assert as follows

wrapper.instance().handleOnClick();
expect(window.location.assign)
 .toBeCalledWith('http://localhost/redirecturl.html');
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late response, but maybe it will be helpful to someone anyway.

You rather don't test `window.location.href` directly. Instead, you stub it or wrap it with another function and check if that wrapper/stub was called. You can then naturally check the URL which was passed.